Issue with Exporting and Importing Realm Settings and Authentication Configuration in Keycloak
I'm facing an issue with exporting and importing realm settings and authentication configuration in Keycloak. Here are the steps I've followed:
Exported the realm to a JSON file using the command:
docker exec –it containerName /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh export --file /tmp/realm-export.json --users skip --realm realmName

Copied the exported JSON file to the local computer using the command:
docker cp containerName:/tmp/realm-export.json /tmp/realm-export.json

Generated a new database in the JSON file using a Python script.
Attempted to import the realm settings and authentication configuration:
Logged in to Keycloak as an admin.
Created a new realm.
Went to Realm settings -> Actions -> Uploaded mynewfile.json (JSON file with new database) -> Selected all resources -> Chose "Overwrite" if a resource already exists -> Clicked "Import".
However, after importing, the realm settings and authentication configuration are not being applied as expected (only users, groups, identity providers, realm/client roles are present). But when I tried to create new realm using this json file, there is an error "Could not create realm Conflict detected. See logs for details". Can someone please guide me on what might be going wrong here?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!
